# String handling in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I have each string below :

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((107.067521 16.873693000000003,107.06849999999997 16.873613000000034)))
```

Now is there any way to group 107.067521 16.8736930000003 into a group, 107.06849999999997 16.873613000000034 into a group and in each group separate them. Example with group 107.067521 16.873693000000003 will split lat=107.067521, lng=16.873693000000003, do the same with the rest of the groups.

Comment: What does "group" mean to you?  Are you talking about grouping in regular expressions?  Or are you talking about splitting the string into fields (parsing)?  Or something else?

Comment: I have a class Point with 2 attributes lat and lng. I want to split the above string to save information into lat vs lng in class Point

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression to parse the input?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd use Split to do all the work:

```
var nums = input.Split(", ()".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var points = new List<Point>();

for(int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i += 2){
  points.Add(new Point {
    Lat = double.Parse(nums[i+1],
    Lon = double.Parse(nums[i])
  });
}
```

Note in WKT representation it's more typical to have it in "Long Lat" order - you've said the lat comes first. If you're absolutely certain your string is "Long Lat" then swap the assignments over inside the loop, but double check first otherwise you might end up drawing your polygons on a completely different part of the planet

Another thing to point out; you've only got a single poly here and if you only ever have one then simple parsing it like above will do, but the use of a multi poly is to keep track of which polygons are supposed to be kept together. Flattening to a list of points will work ok if there is only one poly, but things could go wonky if there really are multiple polys in your string eg

```
MULTIPOLYGON( (1 2,3 4,5 6,1 2) , (7 8,9 10,11 12,7 8) )

POLYGON( (1 2,3 4,5 6,1 2,7 8,9 10,11 12,7 8) )
```

These two are completely different shapes (and the latter doesn't close).. Take care with it, and consider a more involved parsing routine if you truly have multi polys

Comment: Actually i have a string of lots of polys

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.parse ?

Comment: I don't quite understand it, can you give me a specific example ?

Comment: I can't at the moment because the cellphone I'm using doesn't render the docs properly. I'm saying you can use the libraries Microsoft wrote for parsing geography, and then enumerate them yourself to get your points. Pause some test code in the debugger after doing a geography parse and have a look at the object generated. Other wkt parsing libraries exist; there isn't any need to roll your own - eg https://github.com/cschwarz/wkx-sharp

Answer (score 0):

With no regular expression, my approach is to find the text enclosed by the last `(` and the first `)`, then split it using `String.Split` and delimiters of `,` and a space  .  Remove empty entries in case there are multiple spaces.

```cs
string example = @"MULTIPOLYGON(((107.067521 16.873693000000003,107.06849999999997 16.873613000000034)))";

int start = example.LastIndexOf('(');
int end = example.IndexOf(')');
string inside = example.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
string[] fields = inside.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Example
Console.WriteLine($"long1={fields[0]} lat1={fields[1]} long2={fields[2]} lat2={fields[3]}");
```

To be slightly more robust, you could do a first pass to delimit on commas to get long-lat pairs separated by spaces, and then split those fields on spaces. But assuming the input is well formed, the example above should work reasonably well.

Comment: This is not very optimal if my list has more than one

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example that helps me target your performance expectations?

Comment: List of strings I've cut off part of, the actual list link notepab : [link](https://anotepad.com/notes/sswrq7xd) :  https://anotepad.com/notes/sswrq7xd

Comment: I can't believe performance would be a concern here on such a small data set.  But it seems that you may be able to safely assume that `start` is `14` and `end` is `example.Length - 3`.   If you give the final desired data format then I can provide even more optimal code.  But even parsing as doubles, this: `inside.Split(" ,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(double.Parse).ToArray();` takes less than a millisecond.